How does bitshifting 0xFF to the end of an Uint32 form a complete hexadecimal code?
I've been following along to Cave of Programming's C++ for Complete Beginners on Udemy, and in lesson 67 he goes over bitshifting to output certain colour pixels in an SDL window. There's a certain segment where he left-bitshifts a series of Uint8s in a Uint32, and finally adds a 0xFF to the end of it. I'm struggling to figure out why it's at the end.
void Screen::setPixel(int x, int y, Uint8 red, Uint8 green, Uint8 blue) {
    Uint32 color = 0;
    color += red; // 00000080
    color <<= 8; // 00008000
    color += green; // 00008000
    color <<= 8; // 00800000
    color += blue; // 008000FF
    color <<= 8; // 8000FF00
    color += 0xFF; // 8000FF000xFF ???


    m_buffer[(y * SCREEN_WIDTH) + x] = color; // y * screen_width gives 800, 1600 etc pixels; essentially allows row selection

}

This is the function I'm currently working with, with the comments being my thought process following along the tutorial.
Programatically, the integers (128, 0, 255) are used for (red, green, blue), corresponding to (80,00,FF) in hexadecimal
Upon compiling the program, a colour of hex code 0xFF8000FF is displayed, which I verified by placing the same colour found online (https://convertingcolors.com/hex-color-8000FF.html) and checking it side-by-side to make sure it matched the one shown in my SDL window, but I don't understand how the 0xFF "jumps" from the end of the Uint32 to the front.
I'm having difficulty finding resources on this online as I'm not entirely sure how to phrase my question concisely.
Edit: Using the g++ compiler

"I don't understand how the 0xFF "jumps" from the end of the Uint32 to the front." -- Have you narrowed down where it "jumps"? At the end of this function (after the last assignment), what are the values of m_buffer[(y * SCREEN_WIDTH) + x] and color? (I suspect you're seeing a RGBA to ARGB transformation, but your question is not clear about where you see 0xFF8000FF.)

"which I verified by placing the same colour found online (https://convertingcolors.com/hex-color-8000FF.html)" -- That page says that the hex code is 8000FF. It does list 0xFF8000FF as the Android code, but that's a bit indirect to be conclusive, especially since you never mentioned Android..

Apologies - to be transparent, I was following along with the idea of "bitshifting" and writing it out as I shifted, which led me to have a code of 8000FF, with the 0xFF at the end. I've only ever experienced hexadecimal codes that look like 0x[########], so I assumed that either a) I had followed along wrong or b) there was something happening to the Uint32 that I wasn't understanding - I think that in this case (as pointed out by 3CxEZiVlQ), I have my SDL texture in RGBA format.

What you assign in the SDL app is the RGBA color model
[ R  | G  | B  | A  ]
[ 80 | 00 | FF | FF ]

What you see online, is the RGB color model, without the alpha-channel
[ R  | G  | B  ]
[ 80 | 00 | FF ]

For example
[ R  | G  | B  | A  ]
[ 80 | 00 | FF | 80 ]

likely gives on a white background (if I am not mistaken)
[ R  | G  | B  ]
[ 40 | 00 | 80 ]


That makes a lot of sense - I think being used to the "usual" RGB hexadecimals made it hard for me to envision any other format, but this explains the problem I was having. Thank you!
